# I want to load a javascript code before page load.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing problem with a javascript find and replace code, may be this has been answered before but I didn't find any answer helpful to me.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('[class="incometax"]').each(function(i,v){
    var text =$(v).text();
  var new_text = text.replace("old text", "new text");  
  $(v).text(new_text);
});
});
```

It works fine but the problem is when page loads it shows me old text and then blink and change it to new text. I need to load this code before the page load so it doesn't show me old text or blink to change it to new text and directly shows me new text.

Comment: This part `$(document).ready...` is literally saying "Wait until the page loads (mostly), and then do this jQuery." So.... you can take your code out of that and hope it works.

Comment: A quick solution would be to surround all your content in a `div` or a `span` and set it to `display = none;` then after you change the text, just set `display` to block or inline on that element. That may or may not work for you as a solution.

Comment: @TJBlackman No. `$(document).ready` means wait until the DOM is ready. That's very different. Removing the code from this callback *will not work*.

Comment: What should I write instead of $(document).ready ???

Comment: There's a name for what you're experiencing and it's called [Flash of unstyled content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content). In your case I'd seriously consider changing the text on the server-side or starting with the text completely hidden (maybe behind a loading gif) and showing it when it is actually ready to be shown. You might have some success by moving your script as close to (but under) the elements in question and run it without waiting for document load but that is not guaranteed to work for everyone (especially if they have a slow CPU).

Comment: @apokryfos based on the code/question I don't think this is a FOUC issue.

Comment: It's effectively the same thing; it's not a flash of unstyled content, it's a flash of not-yet-search-and-replaced content.

Comment: @Andy in this context the "flash" is the momentary visibility and the "unstyled content" is the old text before it's been replaced

Comment: @TJBlackman I don't need to change complete text inside and element, I just needs to change a word inside the element or class.

Comment: Great... just literally remove the first line of code, and the last line of code. Just don't wrap your code inside the `document.ready()` call. It's (hopefully) that simple.

Comment: you can write javascript code in the head if you want to load javascript before loading body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no client-side ways to change some text, using JS, before the document is loaded.

The only way I see as a solution is to use invisible elements to run the text change script on... Then once the text is changed, make them visible.

**CSS**:

```
.incometax{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

**Script**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[class="incometax"]').each(function(i,v){
    var text =$(v).text();
    var new_text = text.replace("old text", "new text");  
    $(v).text(new_text);
    $(v).css({"visibility":"visible"});  // Make them visible.
  });
});
```

If there is an effect like they do not appear at the same time, here is an alternative:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[class="incometax"]').each(function(i,v){
    var text =$(v).text();
    var new_text = text.replace("old text", "new text");  
    $(v).text(new_text);
  });

  $('[class="incometax"]').css({"visibility":"visible"});  // Make them visible.
});
```

And you can use `$(".incometax")` instead of `$('[class="incometax"]')`. ;)

---

**EDIT**

The same as above can be writen this way, in order to be more concise and more efficient.
It uses `$(this)` and avoid useless lookups. It also uses chaining.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".incometax")
    .each(function(){
      $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/old text/g, "new text"));
    })
    .css({"visibility":"visible"});
});
```

Comment: it only replace 1st old text in content, I have word old text in content multiple times and i need to replace it everywhere instead of just replacing first.

Comment: I edited the last code suggestion with the use of a "regex" as the first argument of `.replace()`... But be careful... There are some characters having special signification in a regex and may need to be escaped. Try your own regex on [regex101](https://regex101.com/#javascript)

Comment: that's fine but the function breaks when I try to remove any html tag which is showing in content. like I need to remove <p>   and </p> which is multiple times in my content, and it worked fine for <p> but when I add / for </p> it breaks and hide complete class.

Comment: Try `.replace(/<\/?p>/g, "")` to remove `<p>` and `</p>`. ;)

Comment: PERFECT PERFECT PERFECT!!! Only one last thing, how I can do it for auto added line break space?

Comment: Try to chain another replace to the first, like this: `.replace(/\n\s*/gm, "")` -- `\n` is for the new line character and `\s*` is for zero or more spaces (folowing the new line char). And notice the additional `m` flag which is for multiline.

Comment: Thank you very much, It is all fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function by the name on load. You can try by using it this way:

```
<body onload="changetext()">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changetext(){
  $('[class="incometax"]').each(function(i,v){
    var text =$(v).text();
    var new_text = text.replace("old text", "new text");  
    $(v).text(new_text);
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: it still blink and then change the text

Comment: `body onload` fires after document.ready would have (it waits for associated images and etc; document.ready only waits for the DOM).

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem since it only changes the text after loading the page.